# is there any way to update app icon without release?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, icons

How to change app icon on Google Play Console and App Store Connect without updating the application? So app icon should change on both android and iOS devices. Is it possible guys?

I didn't found informations about it. But I saw that one application got changed his icon. But I didn't updated those app

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible to change Icon of the app without a new submission.
Not sure if Apple and google is allowing, if they are perhaps you might want to consider having code push https://shorebird.dev for your future releases. this will allow you to push app updates directly to users' devices.

Comment: Since the app icon is in the manifest, which isn't downloadable as part of a flutter package but is a compiled file in the apk, this wouldn't allow the app icon to be updated.